# Get data for form input array using specific key

Tags: javascript, forms, form-data

So, let's say I have an HTML form like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="dummy">
    <input type="text" name="people[0][first_name]" value="John">
    <input type="text" name="people[0][last_name]" value="Doe">
    <input type="text" name="people[1][first_name]" value="Jane">
    <input type="text" name="people[1][last_name]" value="Smith">
</form>
```

And I want to get a JavaScript array that matches the values of `real`. For example:

```
// If there was a sweet function for this...
var people = getFormDataByInputName( 'people' );

// Value of `people` is...
// [
//    {
//        'first_name' : 'John',
//        'last_name'  : 'Doe'
//    },
//    {
//        'first_name' : 'Jane',
//        'last_name'  : 'Smith'
//    }
// ]
```

Is there any easy way of doing that for just a specific form item (in this case, `people`)? Or would I have to serialize the entire form an then just extract the element I want?

I also thought of potentially using the following approach:

```
var formData = new FormData( document.querySelector( '#myForm' ) );
var people = formData.get( 'people' );
```

But that doesn't appear to work; people is just null after that.

Comment: So people is an array of objects and you want an html form to push a new object in people ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with plain js using `reduce` method and return each person is one object.

```js
const form = document.querySelectorAll('#myForm input');
const data = [...form].reduce(function(r, e) {
  const [i, prop] = e.name.split(/\[(.*?)\]/g).slice(1).filter(Boolean)
  if (!r[i]) r[i] = {}
  r[i][prop] = e.value
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(data)
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="dummy">
  <input type="text" name="people[0][first_name]" value="John">
  <input type="text" name="people[0][last_name]" value="Doe">
  <input type="text" name="people[1][first_name]" value="Jane">
  <input type="text" name="people[1][last_name]" value="Smith">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work because to HTML/JS `name` is just a string that it sends to the server when the form is submitted (the name in the name/value pairs).  You might think it is arrays, but HTML/JS doesn't.

So no one-liner to get the job done.  Try this: In your HTML, add `<div class="name">` ...

(UPDATE: thanks for the idea, @Nenad, I've never tried one of these snippets)

```js
var people = [];
$('.name').each(function() {
    people.push({
        first_name: $('input:nth-child(1)', this).val(),
        last_name: $('input:nth-child(2)', this).val()
    });
});
console.log(people);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="dummy">
  <div class="name">
    <input type="text" value="John">
    <input type="text" value="Doe">
  </div>
  <div class="name">
    <input type="text" value="Jane">
    <input type="text" value="Smith">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getObject(name, key) {
  if(key.includes(name)) {
    var splitStr = key.split(/\[|\]/g);
    return {
      index: splitStr[1],
      key: splitStr[3],
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function getFormDataByInputName(name) {
 var formData = new FormData( document.querySelector('#myForm'));
 var results = [];
 for (var key of formData.keys()) {
   var obj = getObject(name, key);
   if (obj) {
      if (results[obj.index]) results[obj.index][obj.key] = formData.get(key);
      else results[obj.index] = { [obj.key]: formData.get(key) };
   }
 }
 return results;
}


var people = getFormDataByInputName('people');

console.log(people);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="dummy">
    <input type="text" name="people[0][first_name]" value="John">
    <input type="text" name="people[0][last_name]" value="Doe">
    <input type="text" name="people[1][first_name]" value="Jane">
    <input type="text" name="people[1][last_name]" value="Smith">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS attribute prefix selector, such as

```
form.querySelectorAll('[name^="people[]"]')
```

You can use a for-loop to get all peoples, as such

```
const MAX_PEOPLES = 2;
const list = [];
for (i = 0; i <= MAX_PEOPLES; i++) {
  const eles = form.querySelectorAll(`[name^="people[${i}]`);
  if (eles.length !== 2)
    break;

  list.push({
    first_name: eles[0].value,
    last_name: eles[1].value
  });
}
```

that yields

```
[
   {
      "first_name":"John",
      "last_name":"Doe"
   },
   {
      "first_name":"Jane",
      "last_name":"Smith"
   }
]
```